# Add TFS Tag with REST API via powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, tfs, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to add a tag to a TFS project using the REST API in Powershell.

I am trying to make this request based on the documentation for
[Visual Studio Integration](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/tags)

I am calling this:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client')
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client')

if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell" -ErrorAction                  SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell"
}
$SrcCollectionUrl = 'http://tfs.myCompany.com:8080/tfs/MyCollection' 
$SrcProjectName = 'myProject' 
[psobject] $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($SrcCollectionUrl)
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStoreFlags]$WorkItemBypass =      [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStoreFlags]::BypassRules

$tfstp = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($SrcCollectionUrl)
$WorkItemStore = New-Object -TypeName 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore' -ArgumentList $tfs.TfsTeamProjectCollection, $WorkItemBypass

$SrcProject = $WorkItemStore.Projects[$SrcProjectName]
$ProjectGuid = Split-Path $SrcProject.Uri -Leaf

$AddTagsUrl = '{0}/_apis/tagging/scopes/{1}/tags?api-version=1.0' -f $SrcCollectionUrl,$ProjectGuid

$newTagParams = @{name="PWCreateTag2"}
$outjson = $newTagParams | ConvertTo-Json
$nresp = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $AddTagsUrl -UseDefaultCredentials  -Body $outjson -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Everything works. The first time. However the documentation states: "If a tag by that name already exists, no tag is created. Instead, the response body includes the existing tag with that name."

The 2nd time I call the line I get: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Anyone have any Idea why this fails the 2nd time?

FYI: TFS Server is 2015, Powershell is V4

Comment: the same PowerShell script works for creating tags in Visual Studio Team Services. I think there is something different in TFS2015.

Answer (score 0):

I created powershell module for this - [tfs](https://github.com/majkinetor/TFS)

To add tags:

```
'tag1','tag2' | % { Add-TFSBuildTag -Id 520 -Tag $_ }
```